# Bluetooth pairing using 32feet is not producing the same result as manual pairing (windows Mobile 6.5.3)

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-mobile-6.5, 32feet

I'm using the 32Feet libraries to establish a pairing between an MC75 and a chip and pin device.

Both the pairing and connection verification using the library appears to work correctly but when creating a virtual com port and then using it as a serial port consistently fails.

Once the pairing has been allegedly established the application then tests the pairing using the virtual com port. 
There is then a separate application that uses this virtual com port but fails to establish the connection unless I delete and recreate the pairing manually on the windows mobile device.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Below are some code snippets...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create the pairing configuration for the bluetooth device.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bluetoothAddress">Bluetooth device address</param>
    /// <param name="passcode">Passcode for the connection</param>
    /// <returns>True if the pairing was created.</returns>
    private bool CreatePairing(BluetoothAddress bluetoothAddress, string passcode)
    {
        BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;
        bool success = false;

        // Get the info of the device and tell it to use the serial port
        var device = new BluetoothDeviceInfo(bluetoothAddress);
        try
        {
            Log.InfoFormat("Pairing with device {0}", bluetoothAddress);

            // Create an end point with the address using a serial port
            var btEndPoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(bluetoothAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort);

            // Ensure the device will use the virtual com port by setting the service state
            device.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.SerialPort, true, true);

            var bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();
            Log.Info("Set Service State of bluetooth device.");

            // Use the address to specify the pairing reqest
            bool pairedState = BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(device.DeviceAddress, passcode);

            Log.Info("Pairing requested");

            // Use the end point to make the connection
            bluetoothClient.Connect(btEndPoint);

            if (bluetoothClient.Connected)
            {
                Log.Info("Paired device connected");

                bluetoothClient.Close();
                success = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // The connection failed so remove the pairing 
                BluetoothSecurity.RemoveDevice(bluetoothAddress);

                // Remove the com port
                device.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.SerialPort, false, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
            BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.PowerOff;
        }

        return success;
    }
```

This is my test method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Alternative method of validating the comms port
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if connection was successful else False.</returns>
    private bool ReconnectDevice2()
    {
        BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;

        bool connectionState = false;
        try
        {
            // Set the port number to the value paired
            string unitPort = "COM9";

            DeviceSerialPort dsp = new DeviceSerialPort(unitPort);

            connectionState = dsp.Open();
            dsp.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
            BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.PowerOff;
        }

        return connectionState;
    }
```

The DeviceSerialPort class

```
namespace PairingTool
{
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using log4net;

/// <summary>
/// Interfaces with a serial port. There should only be one instance of this class for each serial port to be used.
/// </summary>
internal class DeviceSerialPort
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(BluetoothForm));

    private const string ClassName = "DeviceSerialPort";

    internal enum Timeout
    {
        Short = 6000,
        AckWait = 9000,
        CommandResponse = 9000,
        Download = 9000,
        TransactionLoop = 180000,
        Authorisation = 600000
    }

    #region Private Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Serial port class
    /// </summary>
    private SerialPort serialPort;

    /// <summary>
    /// BaudRate set to default for Serial Port Class
    /// </summary>
    private int baudRate;

    /// <summary>
    /// DataBits set to default for Serial Port Class
    /// </summary>
    private int dataBits;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handshake set to default for Serial Port Class
    /// </summary>
    private Handshake handshake;

    /// <summary>
    /// Parity set to default for Serial Port Class
    /// </summary>
    private Parity parity;

    /// <summary>
    /// Communication Port name, not default in SerialPort. Defaulted to COM4 as this seems to be the Thyron default
    /// </summary>
    private string portName;

    /// <summary>
    /// StopBits set to default for Serial Port Class
    /// </summary>
    private StopBits stopBits;

    /// <summary>
    /// continueRead when set to false will interupt the current reading of the port.
    /// </summary>
    private bool continueRead;

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets BaudRate (Default: 9600)
    /// </summary>
    internal int BaudRate
    {
        get { return this.baudRate; }
        set { this.baudRate = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets DataBits (Default: 8)
    /// </summary>
    internal int DataBits
    {
        get { return this.dataBits; }
        set { this.dataBits = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Handshake (Default: None)
    /// </summary>
    internal Handshake Handshake
    {
        get { return this.handshake; }
        set { this.handshake = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Parity (Default: None)
    /// </summary>
    internal Parity Parity
    {
        get { return this.parity; }
        set { this.parity = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets PortName (Default: COM1)
    /// </summary>
    internal string PortName
    {
        get { return this.portName; }
        set { this.portName = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets StopBits (Default: One}
    /// </summary>
    internal StopBits StopBits
    {
        get { return this.stopBits; }
        set { this.stopBits = value; }
    }

    internal string ErrorMessage
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    #endregion

    internal DeviceSerialPort()
    {
        this.serialPort = new SerialPort();
        this.baudRate = 19200;
        this.dataBits = 8;
        this.handshake = Handshake.None;
        this.parity = Parity.None;
        this.stopBits = StopBits.One;
    }

    internal DeviceSerialPort(string comPort)
    {
        this.serialPort = new SerialPort();
        this.portName = comPort;
        this.baudRate = 19200;
        this.dataBits = 8;
        this.handshake = Handshake.None;
        this.parity = Parity.None;
        this.stopBits = StopBits.One;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the current settings for the COM port and tries to open it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if successful, false otherwise</returns>
    internal bool Open()
    {
        bool success = false;

        // Initialise the port prior to connecting
        this.serialPort = new SerialPort(this.portName);

        this.serialPort.Close();    // Force the serial port to be closed to ensure a stable state.

        this.serialPort.BaudRate = this.baudRate;
        this.serialPort.DataBits = this.dataBits;
        this.serialPort.Handshake = this.handshake;
        this.serialPort.Parity = this.parity;
        this.serialPort.PortName = this.portName;
        this.serialPort.StopBits = this.stopBits;
        this.serialPort.ReadTimeout = (int)Timeout.AckWait;
        this.serialPort.WriteTimeout = (int)Timeout.CommandResponse;

        try
        {
            this.serialPort.Open();
            success = this.serialPort.IsOpen;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "Port is already open.";
            Log.Error(this.ErrorMessage);
            Log.DebugFormat("Exception {0}, {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            success = false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "Invalid port name or the port is not supported.";
            Log.Error(this.ErrorMessage);
            Log.DebugFormat("Exception {0}, {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            success = false;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "Access to the port was denied.";
            Log.Error(this.ErrorMessage);
            Log.DebugFormat("Exception {0}, {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            success = false;
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "The port was available but a connection could not be made, try again.";
            Log.Error(this.ErrorMessage);
            Log.DebugFormat("Exception {0}, {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            success = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = "Unexpected Exception";
            Log.Error(this.ErrorMessage);
            Log.DebugFormat("Exception {0}, {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }

    public bool IsOpen()
    {
        return this.serialPort.IsOpen;
    }

    internal void Close()
    {
        if (this.serialPort != null)
        {
            Log.Info("Closing the COM port.");
            this.serialPort.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: AFAIK MS puts some additional changes in the registry during pairing. Do you really need a pairing? Do you really need a COM port? Why not use the Bluetooth connection via network socket (or stream)?

Comment: We have to use a COM port because my application is establishing the pairing but a 3rd party application is using the details of that pairing to open a serial port and that requires a virtual com port be used.

Comment: Is the target BT device requesting a PIN? If not, just use RegisterDevice with the com port and the BT device address.

Comment: We are required to supply a pin for the pairing but this is not then used for communicating.

Comment: Your code is phenomenally helpful! Do you have an example of how you use the DeviceSerialPort class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with how the connection pairing is stored in the registry.

It turns out that when you open a serial port , you need to let it stabilise before doing anything with it. Ideally, you'd only get a true from the "IsOpen" property once it's stabilised but as you don't, you just need to add a delay...

```
            this.serialPort.Open();

            // Delay to ensure that the serial port is in a stable state
            Thread.Sleep(StabilisationDelay);

            success = this.serialPort.IsOpen;
```